# Scala val syntax: What does val myVal:{ def ... } mean?

Tags: function, scala, declaration, subtyping

I am new to Scala and to funcprog.

I have a piece of code (some of you might recognize it):

```
    trait SwingApi {

      type ValueChanged <: Event

      val ValueChanged: {
        def unapply(x: Event): Option[TextField]
      }
      ...
     }
```

where I do not underestand what val ValueChanged: {...} is.

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508529/subtype-in-scala-what-is-type-x-y) I sort of learned that

```
type ValueChanged <: Event
```

and

```
val ValueChanged: {
            def unapply(x: Event): Option[TextField]
          }
```

are two unrelated things because they are in different namespaces, etc, and  *type ValueChanged* is an abstract subtype of *Event*.

Good, then I try in a Scala worksheet:

```
type myString <: String

 val myString: {
    def myfunc(x: String): String
  }
```

and it shows me an error "only classes can have declared and undefined members"... Isn't it a similar construction?

Finally, the questions are:

- what is ValueChanged in *val ValueChanged* part of code?
- is it truely so unrelated to *type ValueChanged <: Event*
- what does this syntax mean:

  val myVal:{def func{x:T}:T}

? What's the name of the value, its type and its actual value here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{def unapply(x: Event): Option[TextField]}
```

is a structural Type, it means that it accepts any Object that has an unapply method with a Event as Parameter and Option[TextField] as return value.
It is most often used similar to Duck typing, e.g.:

```
def foo(canQuack: {def quack(): Unit}) = {
  canQuack.quack()
}
object Bar{
   def quack(): Unit = print("quack")
}
object Baz{
   def bark(): Unit = print("bark")
}
foo(Bar) //works
foo(Baz) //compile error
```

so

```
type StructuralType = {def unapply(x: Event): Option[TextField]}
val ValueChanged: StructuralType
```

declares a val with the name ValueChanged and with the Type StructuralType, but assigns no value, that makes only sense in a trait or abstract class, thats why your example doesnt work.

So what

```
trait SwingApi {
...
  val ValueChanged: {
    def unapply(x: Event): Option[TextField]
  }
...
}
```

means is that the trait SwingApi can only be applied to Objects/Classes that have a val with the name ValueChanged and whatever value is assigned to it, has an unapply method

```
trait SwingApi {
  val ValueChanged: {
    def unapply(x: Event): Option[TextField]
  }
}
//works:
object Bar extends SwingApi{
  val ValueChanged = {
    def unapply(x: Event): Option[TextField] = None
  }
}
//compile error:
object Baz extends SwingApi{
  val ValueChanged = {
    //wrong name
    def foo(x: Event): Option[TextField] = None
  }
}
//compile error:
object Baz2 extends SwingApi{
  val ValueChanged = {
    //wrong input/output type
    def unapply(): Unit = {}
  }
}
```

<sub>All code untested</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much  for the extensive explanation with examples! It couldn't be clearer!