# How to distinguish parameteric types?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, scala-reflect, erasure

I am confused about subtypes in Scala. My major question is how to distinguish `C[T1]` from `C[T2]`. There are two scenarios:

1. `C[T1]` "equals" `C[T2]` because they are all subtypes of `C`.
2. `C[T1]` does not "equal" `C[T2]` because `C[T1]` and `C[T2]` are different types eventually.

I have tried some ways like `.getClass`, seems that this strategy won't work because we have primitive types.

```
println(List[Int](1).getClass == List[Double](1.0).getClass) // True
println(List[Int](1).getClass.getCanonicalName) // scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
println(Array[Int](1).getClass == Array[Double](1.0).getClass) // False
println(Array[Int](1).getClass.getCanonicalName) // int[]
```

I now wonder is there some way I can do this?

Comment: Take a look to type erasure in Scala: https://squidarth.com/scala/types/2019/01/11/type-erasure-scala.html

Comment: What is the meta problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Previous OP's question was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002546/is-there-some-way-in-scala-that-i-can-return-a-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List[Int]` and `List[Double]` have the same **class**, but different **types**.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

println(typeOf[List[Int]] =:= typeOf[List[Double]])//false
println(typeOf[List[Int]].typeConstructor =:= typeOf[List[Double]].typeConstructor)//true
println(typeOf[List[Int]])//List[Int]
println(showRaw(typeOf[List[Int]]))//TypeRef(SingleType(SingleType(ThisType(<root>), scala), scala.package), TypeName("List"), List(TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Int, List())))

println(classOf[List[Int]] == classOf[List[Double]])//true
println(classOf[List[Int]])//class scala.collection.immutable.List
println(classOf[List[Int]].getCanonicalName)//scala.collection.immutable.List
```

`Array[Int]` and `Array[Double]` have different both classes and types.

```
println(typeOf[Array[Int]] =:= typeOf[Array[Double]])//false
println(typeOf[Array[Int]].typeConstructor =:= typeOf[Array[Double]].typeConstructor)//true
println(typeOf[Array[Int]])//Array[Int]
println(showRaw(typeOf[Array[Int]]))//TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Array, List(TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Int, List())))

println(classOf[Array[Int]] == classOf[Array[Double]])//false
println(classOf[Array[Int]])//class [I
println(classOf[Array[Int]].getCanonicalName)//int[]
```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html

https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html

[Type Erasure in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570948/type-erasure-in-scala)

> `C[T1]` "equals" `C[T2]` because they are all subtypes of `C`.

They are not **subtypes**.

https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#conformance

[Subtype in Scala: what is "type X <: Y"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508529/subtype-in-scala-what-is-type-x-y)